# insert null in texbox as dataset give me nonullexception

Tags: c#

I have a textbox that cannot be null. when the textbox is null dataset give me error but when I type characters in textbox and then delete them, dataset doesn't give me error.because this textbox in dataset shouldn't be null. how do I check it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the `String.IsNullOrEmpty` property to check the string *before* submitting it to your backend storage. You can read the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When you type characters in a Textbox and delete them all, it does not go back to being `NULL`.

The textbox is now **Empty**.

You can check it this way:

`if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.text))`